# Can I extract google custom search results to determine output in a .NET site?

Tags: asp.net, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I'm working on have a property listing asp.NET website and the current search function is pretty crappy. I want to know if I can use the Google Custom Search API to extract the results but still present them in the same way there are now (comprehensive listing items with pricing, images, etc. Here's the current look: http://temporadaplus.com/Aluguel-Por-Temporada.aspx?pais=Brasil ). Each listing item is created via a .NET itemtype. SO basically all I need is to know how to go about using Google's much better results without altering anything visually.

I came across this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040824/how-can-i-do-a-search-with-google-custom-search-api-for-net) but I am not sure its exactly what I;m looking for. Any ideas or comments are appreciated.